# Is it ok to use 電車 for non-electric trains?

Tags: meaning

電車 has the kanji for "electric" in it, but is it more or less ok to use it even for non-electric trains, such as steam trains? I saw a steam-powered train being used as the picture for that word in Duolingo.

Comment: City people often believe 汽車 only refers to "that black SL". If you used [電車 in Tokushima prefecture](https://matome.naver.jp/odai/2140278611640243301), you're an outsider. Seriously.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I was corrected yesterday on this very point when playing [Great Western Trail](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/193738/great-western-trail) in Japanese.

The people I was with most assuredly only use 汽車 for steam locomotives versus 電車 for modern electric rail trains. They found my periodic use of 電車 humorous but wrong enough that they vocally corrected it twice...

In the case of the game the trains are 19th steam locomotives, but I've had the same experience riding the [ノロッコ号](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%8F%E3%81%97%E3%82%8D%E6%B9%BF%E5%8E%9F%E3%83%8E%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%82%B3%E5%8F%B7) to Furano.

If you want a universal word for train, there's 列車 and for passenger train 客車

Comment: 汽車 with Diesel engines are not uncommon at all in rural areas of Japan today. Many trains running in Chugoku & Shikoku are 汽車 (And people there *do* call them 汽車). See: [鉄道の電化#旅客線がほぼ非電化の県](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%89%84%E9%81%93%E3%81%AE%E9%9B%BB%E5%8C%96#.E6.97.85.E5.AE.A2.E7.B7.9A.E3.81.8C.E3.81.BB.E3.81.BC.E9.9D.9E.E9.9B.BB.E5.8C.96.E3.81.AE.E7.9C.8C)

Answer (score 7):

Not so. As explained [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/ja/%E9%9B%BB%E8%BB%8A), the term 電車 technically refers to an electric train that either:

1. uses an onboard power storage to run its electric engine, or
2. uses a power transfer device that transmits electricity from a power line to the engine

Any train that uses an internal combustion engine to create electricity that subsequently powers an electric motor is not categorized as a 電車 but a 電気式気動車 (electric-powered combustion engine train) instead.

Answer (score 6):

Steamed powered trains are called 汽車. I've seen it Japanese novel in the old times.

There are examples of it [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/51771/example/m0u/). One of the examples:

> ･･･――「美華禁酒会長ヘンリイ・バレット氏は京漢鉄道の**汽車**中に頓死したり。同氏は薬罎を手に死しいたるより、自殺の疑いを生ぜしが、罎中の水薬は分析の結果、アルコオル類と判明したるよし。」･･･<芥川竜之介「馬の脚」青空文庫>

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 types of train based on the motive power:

1) 蒸気動車 (steam powered train, 汽車 is more often used)

2) [気動車](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%B0%97%E5%8B%95%E8%BB%8A) (internal combustion engine powered train, even it has electric traction motors)

3) [電車](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%9B%BB%E8%BB%8A) (electric powered train)

The difference between those three is trivial as vast majority of Japanese trains still in operation uses electricity as primary power.

More specifically, as defined by 新明解国語辞典, 電車 refers to any electric-powered passenger or freight trains which connected to either overhead wires or other conductive devices using current collector (集電装置).

> **電車**: 電力でレールの上を走る装置が付いている車両（から成る列車）。

There are more general words to refer trains such as 列車 (train set), 客車 (passenger train, as shortened form of 旅客列車) & 貨車 (freight train, as shortened form of 貨物列車).

On the other hand, "汽車" formerly refers to [trains hauled/powered by a steam locomotive (蒸気機関車)](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1361047358) as it's common for railway lines in the past, but as nowadays all internal combustion engine trains (either self-powered or locomotive-hauled) uses either "汽車" or "気動車" when steam locomotives more often used for excursion or historical trains.

[This article](http://www.hitachinaka-rail.co.jp/journal/2013/04/11/%E9%9B%BB%E8%BB%8A%E3%80%80%E6%B0%97%E5%8B%95%E8%BB%8A%E3%80%80%E6%B1%BD%E8%BB%8A/) also described the problem of "電車" to mention any "passenger trains" regardless of its prime mover for Japanese natives but seems having little influence.

Comment: "*貨車*" No... Really? Would anyone understand it as a "*freight train*"? 貨物列車 is a common, unambiguous term.

Comment: I know that 貨物列車 is the common term, but I specifically mentions this: [貨車](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B2%A8%E8%BB%8A). There exists other usage of "貨車" to refer trucks/lorries, but it's not in this case.

Comment: Sorry, but the first sentence of the article which you linked proves 貨車 is **not** a freight train: 貨物を輸送するための列車（貨物列車）に用いられる**車両**を指す呼称。

Answer (score 1):

> 電車 has the kanji for "electric" in it, but is it more or less ok to use it even for non-electric trains, such as steam trains?

No.

narutoさんのコメントを見て、徳島の人ではありませんがその地方の過去を含めた公共交通機関の状況がどうであったかで、乗り物の呼び名が違うことを改めて感じました。

実際に徳島の「電車のような」乗り物を見ました。立派に電車に見えますが、電気を取り入れる電線のようなものが見えません。高架線からではなく、地下鉄でよくあるように地上配線から電気をとり入れるのでなければ、何でしょう。一両目の屋根が煤｛すす｝で黒くなっていますので、ディーゼル機関で動くのでしょうか。本当は、この写真から電線が見えないだけで立派に「電車」なのでしょう。

質問者の中にも出て来る蒸気機関車（a steam-powered train）の次に登場したのはディーゼル機関車です。蒸気機関車の石炭の燃焼で出る煙（お客様には煤｛すす｝）の害を抑えるためです。ディーゼル機関でも、石炭の煙ほどではありませんが、石油系燃料燃焼の排気ガスは出ます。蒸気機関車のように列車を牽引するだけの車両です。ディーゼル機関車と並行して登場したのが、ディーゼルカーと言われるもので、客車とディーゼル機関車が一体になった徳島の写真のようなもので、外見は電車そのものです。お客様への煤の被害は大変少なくなりました。

因みに、日本で最初の海底トンネルである関門トンネルでは、蒸気機関車のまま走ると、長いトンネル内で十分に処理できない煙（お客様には煤｛すす｝）の害を防ぐために、トンネルに入る前と出た後（下関と門司の各々の駅）とで、蒸気機関車と煙の出ない機関車につなぎなおしておりました。そのときの煙の出ない機関車は何だったのでしょうか。ディーゼル機関車なのか、それか電気機関車なのかいずれかだと思います。

ところで、「電車」は最初は路面電車を指す簡単な呼び名として使われました。少し大きな都市では、北から南まで、路面電車がありました。今でも少し残っていますね。
路面電車と国鉄（今のＪＲ）の乗り物とを同時に使える、あるいは、国鉄の乗り物だけを使えるお客様は、路面電車は「電車」、国鉄（今のＪＲ）が運営する軌道を走るものを「汽車」ときちんと区別して使っていました。

最初は、「電車」は正式に電気で走り、「汽車」は蒸気機関で走っておりましたので、言葉と実体とが一致しておりました。

徳島は想像するのに、路面電車はなかったのかもしれません。従って全国統一の「汽車」、いわゆる国鉄（後にＪＲ）の乗り物を指す用語が車両を牽引する動力の変遷にもかかわらず今でも使われているものと思われます。

日本全体では、都会では、路面電車がなくなり、国鉄も公害防止のために、ディーゼル機関車から電気機関車になり、そのうち、機関車の機関部部が小型化され客車の先端部分に電気機関部分が設置されるようになってきました。外観はまるで徳島の汽車です。国鉄と並行して私鉄も普及しました。私鉄は大都市では一部の線路が地下に潜りました。さらに、地下鉄だけの路線もできました。しかも近頃は相互乗り入れと称して地下鉄と地上を走る乗り物もかなりつながってきました。その上を走る乗り物はいずれも「徳島の電車のような姿をした汽車」と同じ姿の電車です。動力源はもちろん電気です。もはや路面電車とＪＲの乗り物との区別が車両の姿で区別できなくなってきました。「電車」が路面電車から卒業です。

実は乗っている人は、今乗っている乗り物の動力源が電気であるのかどうかはほとんど考えていないと思います。要するに、最初は動力源をきちんと区別としておりましたが、今では「電車」と言えばモノレールなどの例外を除けば、一般に、軌道を利用して走る乗り物全てを指しております。私鉄であろうが地下鉄であろうが区別なしです。ＪＲとＪＲ以外を区別して、「電車」にＪＲを含めないという人もいるでしょう。でも、ＪＲを区別するときは、ＪＲに対して地下鉄で行くとか小田急で行くとかいう場合でしょう。しかも、ＪＲのホームで近づいてくるものに対して「電車が来た」といいますので、間違いなく、全部「電車」と呼んでいますで問題なしです。
その意味では質問者が何でも「電車」というのかという質問は少しは合っていますが、さすがに今は懐かしい蒸気機関車を「電車」とは言いません。

そのうち、「電車」の動力源が電気でなく、水素燃料のようなものに変わっても、人々は徳島の人々のように、昔の用語をそのまま使い続けて、「水素に乗る」とは言わず、「電車に乗る」「というのかも知れません。

Comment: 事実誤認があるようですが、徳島の汽車を汽車と呼ぶのは本当に汽車（ディーゼル気動車）だからです。​徳島は歴史上唯一電車が走ったことがない県‌​ですが、他にもかなり汽車が残っている県は[北から南までたくさんあり](http://deadsection.image.coocan.jp/dead_sec/electrify.htm)、実際に[汽車と呼ばれています](https://togetter.com/li/1056266)。もちろん区別する習慣がない人も多く、何を見ても電車と呼ぶ東京人や何を見ても汽車と呼ぶ田舎の老人とかはいます。

Comment: @naruto: 情報ありがとうございます。徳島は電線が見えなかったのと屋根が黒かったのでディーゼルカーかなと思っておりましたが、そんなわけないなと思って電車かなと思った次第です。いまだにあるのですね。ところで、ディーゼル気動車という言葉は初めて聞きました。私はあの写真はディーゼルカーと呼んでおりました。ところで、鹿児島や熊本のように今でも市電（?）が走っているところの人は、実際のＪＲの電気で動く列車をどう呼ぶのだろうかというのが疑問です。たぶん新幹線は「新幹線」でしょうが、それ以外の列車（電気で動く）は「汽車」と呼ぶのでしょうか。

Comment: @naruto: 実際にどう呼んでいるのか考えると、人が乗るものに限って言うと、乗り物の姿をイメージしているときはバスや車と区別して地下鉄でも私鉄でもＪＲでも何でも「電車」と言い、経路を意識したときには、「ＪＲ」とか「何々線」とか言ったり聞いたりしているようです。昔は「電車」と言えば市電あるいは路面電車を指し、今と全く違ったものを指していました。そして、電車が走っている道路は「電車 [道]｛みち｝ 」と言ってました。

Comment: 県別の文化（私鉄や路面電車だけを電車と呼んで区別するとか）が色々あるようですが細かすぎるので、「地方ではまだまだ汽車はメジャーな存在です」くらいで十分かなと思います。「箱型の車両は全部電車と呼べばいい」みたいに思っている人を見ると、特に鉄道ファンではない私でも「この都会人め」と内心思ってしまいますが(^^;)